# How to perform logic operations on dataframes in for loops?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, logical-operators

I have 4 dataframes all with one column that joins them `ID`

I used this line of code to merge all 4 into one df:

```
frame = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

df_final = reduce(lambda left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on='ID'), frame)
```

Now I want to loop through `df_final` but only for where `ID` equals 1 and insert the row that comes up into an API.

I created this code to try:

```
for i in df_final:
    if df_final.loc[df_final['ID'] == 1]:
        df_final_1 = df_final.loc[df_final['SID'] == 1]
        data = {
        'token': 'xxx',
        'number':  df_final_1.number,
        'ID':df_final_1.ID + df_final.ID2,
        'link':df_final_1.URL,
        }
        r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,params=data)
    else:
        print('fail')
```

I keep getting error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I know it has to do with these lines of code in the loop, but not sure what:

```
 if df_final.loc[df_final['ID'] == 1]:
        df_final_1 = df_final.loc[df_final['ID'] == 1]
```

Ideally I dont want to create another dataframe to hold the value I am trying to subset out of `df_final`

Comment: where is you `i` in forloop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df_final.loc[df_final['ID'] == 1]` returns a `DataFrame` containing the rows where `'ID' == 1`, not a boolean value. Since that produces a frame of only the rows you want anyway, just iterate over it using `itertuples()`:

```
for row in df_final[df_final['ID'] == 1].itertuples():
    data = {
    'token': 'xxx',
    'number':  row.number,
    'ID':row.ID + row.ID2,
    'link':row.URL,
    }
    r = requests.post(url,headers=headers,params=data)
```